# how to print std::map with spdlog

Tags: c++, spdlog

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> o;
    o["foo"] = "foo value";
    spdlog::info(o);
    return 0;
}
```

Got error: 
static_assert failed due to requirement 'formattable' "Cannot format argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types"

Comment: You linked to the documentation.  So what is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried following the link and implementing a formatter?

Comment: I following the link , but got error : class template specialization of 'formatter' not in a namespace enclosing 'v6'

Answer (score 0):

spdlog only support types that have `operator <<` (with `#include <fmt/ostream.h>`)

You have 2 options:

- Implement function: `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const std::map<std::string, std::string>&)`
- Log key and value in the loop:

```
for (const auto&[k, v] : o)
{
    spdlog::info("key is {}, value is {}", k, v);
}
```